# What mirror does Linode use for their stretch repository?

Tags: debian, terminal, apt

I am currently running Debian 8.1 Jessie and am considering updating to Debian 9 Stretch so I can install the newer version of TeamTalk from www.bearware.dk/.

I am using [this article](https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch/) and changed every instance of J/jessie to S/stretch, but I am getting these errors.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://mirrors.linode.com/stretch/dists/stretch/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:3c01:1::607e:6379 80]                          

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used
```

I was able to get to

```
 Get:16 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/non-free 
 Translation-en [691 B]   
 Fetched 35.9 kB in 4s (7,377 B/s)
```

So, it was able to download most of them from the debian.org or security.debian.org site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These sources are working for stretch:

```
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch main contrib non-free

# stable-updates
#deb http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```